# Rewrite to a new domain? with url query? not working. :( help

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this rewrite rule...

Redirect all initial request from world.example.com to web.example.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^world\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://web.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which works great. But, some of my applications has...

```
https://world.example.com/approvals/?id=b47b5256567
```

Unfortunately, it is not being redirected properly to web.example.com. Instead, it just goes to web.example.com without the query params.

How could I make all request redirect properly to web.example.com along with the query params?

Basically, what it should do...

```
https://world.example.com/approvals/?id=b47b5256567
then
https://web.example.com/approvals/?id=b47b5256567
```

Just changing the world to web and passing the query string.

Help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use the complicated rewrite engine to do this. Just use [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect):

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName world.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://web.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

The `Redirect` directive automatically preserves everything that comes after what you're redirecting.

Comment: That's nice. Hold-on, let me try. Should I turn off the RewriteEngine Off also?

Comment: The RewriteEngine is not used by the Redirect directive, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Got it! It worked! But, only on http. If a https://world.example.com link was used, it just redirects to the main page without the query https://web.example.com.

Not sure if this might just be me, but my world.example.com (is a self signed certificate), not sure if this is causing the problem.

But, overall - the solutions fits easily. And thank you.

Comment: There may indeed be some odd interactions between http and https when using this. If that continues to be a problem, it could be a topic for another question. :)

Comment: Thank you, it`s working! By the way, We can do it with Nginx, too. - [Nginx Redirect (Rewrite) Old Domain To New Domain With HTTP 301](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsd-nginx-rewrite-old-domain-to-new-domain/)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use the "Query String Append" flag `[R=301,L,QSA]`.

Comment: Yeah, but the rewrite is a bit complicated.

Comment: Well, I don't think so. But of couse Greg Hewgill's suggestion is much more professional, assuming you have access to the server config files.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it with Nginx, too.

```
server {
  listen 80:
  server_name: world.example.com    

  # URL redirect
  #rewrite ^ http://web.example.com$request_uri? permanent;
  rewrite ^ $scheme://web.example.com$request_uri permanent;
  #rewrite ^ $scheme://web.example.com permanent;
  #rewrite ^ $scheme://web.example.com;
}
```

Reference:

- [Nginx Redirect (Rewrite) Old Domain To New Domain With HTTP 301](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsd-nginx-rewrite-old-domain-to-new-domain/)